# Could not find main class in email app Java

Tags: java

```
Error: Unable to load main class emailapp.Emailapp in module projects
```

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: emailapp/EmailApp (wrong name: emailapp/Emailapp) Cant Find Java class please help im trying to make an email application in Java
 So there are two files one for the main and one for the class so everytime i run the main file it doesnt work and shows that error that i am having troubles
I try solutions for classpaths around youtube but still got this error even for environment variables

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Email {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String department;
    private int mailboxCapacity;
    private String alternateEmail;


    // Constructor to recieve first name and last name
    public Email(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        System.out.println("EMAIL CREATED:" + this.firstName + " " +this.lastName);
        // Call a method that is asking for the department and return
        this.department = setDepartment();
    }
    // Ask the Department
    private String setDepartment() {
        System.out.print("Enter the department\n1 for Sales\n2 for Development\n3 for Accounting\n0 for none");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int depChoice = in.nextInt();
        if (depChoice == 1) {return "sales";}
        else if (depChoice == 2) {return "dev";}
        else if (depChoice == 3) {return "acct";}
        else {return "";}
    }


    // Generate a random password

    // Set the mailbox capacity

    // Set the alternate email

    // Change the password
}
```

SECOND FILE

```
package emailapp;

public class EmailApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Email eml = new Email("John","Carl");
    }

}
```

***Please help***

Comment: Can you explain where are you trying to run this application from? from command line or from and IDE like intellij or eclipse etc?

Answer (score 0):

How do you run your Main? Cmd Line or IDE?
Suppose you're running this in IDE, you should try `clean` `rebuild` your project first. 
And the code looks very odd, better refactor to

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter the department\n1 for Sales\n2 for Development\n3 for Accounting\n0 for none");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int depChoice = in.nextInt();
        String department = "";
        if (depChoice == 1) department = "sales";
        else if (depChoice == 2)  department = return "dev";
        else if (depChoice == 3)  department = return "acct";
        Email eml = new Email("John","Carl", department);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback but i found the error it was due to the mispell of my class i appreciate the suggestion Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have given your class name as `EmailApp` but it is trying to load `Emailapp` if your using CLI then check for case sensitivity. If you are using Eclipse OR any other IDE then is should work fine after importing correct packages.

Since your both files are in different packages so `Email class` can not be identified in `EmailApp class` First import all correct packages you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the help i was able to fix it turns out i just had a mispell on the class name Thank you so much!!